# delete one record from database using UITableView and Core Data

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, core-data

I am writing a simple app which lets users add entries to a database. The data is displayed in a UITableView. What I can't figure out is how to delete just one record from the database using the swipe-to-delete functionality of a tableview. I know that the code goes in this method:

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

}
```

But I don't know how to fetch the record of the database that populates the cell that has been swiped.

I have a method which deletes all cells when the user clicks on a button on the navigation bar:

```
-(void)deleteAll {

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Parameters" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSError *error;
NSArray *items = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in items) {
    [context deleteObject:managedObject];
}
if (![context save:&error]) {

}

[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

But I don't how to customize this code to delete one record at a time. Any help to get me started would be appreciated.

I have this method as well...I would think this would delete the record permanently but it doesn't...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:        (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    // Delete the row from the data source
    [self.arr removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
}

[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same swipe to delete functionality using [MCSwipeTableCell](https://github.com/alikaragoz/MCSwipeTableViewCell)

For deleting a particular row from table with animation do this:

```
 //I am passing 0,0 so you gotta pass the row that was deleted.
 NSIndexPath *indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]

 [self.yourTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

For deleting from core data do this:

```
YourCustomModel *modelObj;

NSManagedObjectContext *context= yourmanagedObjectContext;
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"YourCustomModel" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"yourField == %@", passTheFieldValueOfTheRowDeleted];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if ([results count]>0)
{
    modelObj = (Customers *)[results objectAtIndex:0];
}

[context deleteObject:modelObj];

if (![context save:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Sorry, couldn't delete values %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.. Just add a predicate to the fetch request.

```
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(somePropertyInParameters = %d)",value]; 
   [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];`
```

Also, you can get the index path of the swiped cell (and the Parameter object) in this method

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
```

Comment: I have this method commitEditingStyle already, but I don't understand what value I pass into the NSPredicate predicateWithFormat method. Forgive me, I'm brand new to Core Data and still pretty new to coding overall.

Comment: Your table view must contain an array of parameter class objects.Pick the specific parameter object using the index path of the -commitEditingStyle method. Then pass any of the instance variables and its value as argument for the predicate. If it is still difficult to understand, please post the header file of your Parameter object and maybe i can help you out.